# How to update tiles in Windows Phone 7 Mango?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm playing a little with the new Mango APIs.
I'm trying to update the application tile using a Background Agent.

How I can retrieve the current StandardTileData values? There is a way to do so or I have to
keep track of it in the IsolatedStorage?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no current way to get the StandardTileData from an existing Tile. Best bet would be to not use the Tile as a state store anyway (i.e. get the count from the tile, increment it and update it), but rather to use Isolated Storage as you suggest

Answer (score 0):

Store a identifier in the tile's URI, and then retrieve data from the IsolatedStorage (or a remote service or storage, such as Twitter).